# GDAL: Reprojecting geotiff from LATLONG to UTM

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, utm

I have a file in geotiff format, with coordinates in WGS84.
I would need to convert from WGS84 to UTM.

When I launch the code via GDAL:
gdalwarp -t_srs '+ proj = utm + zone = 37 + datum = WGS84 + units = m + no_defs' test_geotiff test_utm.tif

I get:
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
'+ proj = utm

what can I do?

Comment: Take the spaces between the + and the argument, or use the epsg code instead of the proj definition

Answer (score 1):

If your desired UTM Zone is:

- north of the equator, use [EPSG:32637](https://epsg.io/32637) (WGS 84 / UTM zone 37N):

```
  gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:32637 test.tif test_utm.tif
```

- south of the equator, use [EPSG:32737](https://epsg.io/32737) (WGS 84 / UTM zone 37S)

```
  gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:32737 test_geo.tif test_utm.tif
```